# Angular.js directive isolated scope not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a angular directive. 
I am binding a property to isolated scope in directive like

```
scope : {
   contentModel : '='
}
```

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Tc markdown directive
 */
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

myapp.directive('tcMarkdown',[function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = '<div><div class="row"><!--Content edit pane --><div class="col-md-12"><textarea class="form-control editor" ng-model="someobj.text.data"></textarea></div></div></div>{{contentModel}}';
  directive.scope = {
    contentModel : '='
  };

  directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.options = {selected : 0};
    scope.$watch(function() {
      return scope.options.selected;
    }, function(newVal) {
      if(newVal===1) {
        scope.buttonCaption = {text : 'Edit'};
      } else if(newVal === 0) {
        scope.buttonCaption = {text : 'Preview'};
      }
    });
  };
  return directive;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
<data-tc-markdown content-model="content"></data-tc-markdown>
</div>
```

The two way binding is not working.

As I am typing in textarea the model is not updated.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you are binding the internal `contentModel` to your `textarea`.

Here is an [updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rhswn7f/).

I replaced the `someobj.text.data` assigned to `ng-model` with `contentModel`:

```
  myapp.directive('tcMarkdown',[function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = '<div><div class="row"><!--Content edit pane --><div class="col-md-12"><textarea class="form-control editor" ng-model="contentModel"></textarea></div></div></div>';
  directive.scope = {
    contentModel : '='
  };

  directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.options = {selected : 0};
    scope.$watch(function() {
      return scope.options.selected;
    }, function(newVal) {
      if(newVal===1) {
        scope.buttonCaption = {text : 'Edit'};
      } else if(newVal === 0) {
        scope.buttonCaption = {text : 'Preview'};
      }
    });
  };
  return directive;
}]);
```

And then I pulled `{{contentModel}}` out to make sure that `{{content}}` binds in the outer scope:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<data-tc-markdown content-model="content"></data-tc-markdown>
    {{content}}
</div>
```

this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The "content" variable should be defined on an outer scope of your directive. For example, see below: I defined content1 and content2 on an outer controller. These contain the values themselves.

http://jsfiddle.net/jajtzyhh/3/

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.content1 = 'Hello';
    $scope.content2 = 'World';
}]);


<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <data-tc-markdown content-model="content1"></data-tc-markdown>
        <data-tc-markdown content-model="content2"></data-tc-markdown>
    </div>
</div>
```